# Urllib2 gets different html source

Tags: python, html, web, screen-scraping, urllib2

I want the HTML of http://fiverr.com/logo_business/design-a-killer-high-quality-effective-and-custom-made-logo-for-your-company-business-website-or-personal-use using urllib2.
But it doesn't give me the HTML I get via my browser...

My code:

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request('http://fiverr.com/logo_business/design-a-killer-high-quality-effective-and-custom-made-logo-for-your-company-business-website-or-personal-use')
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20130406 Firefox/23.0')
data = opener.open(request).read()
print data
```

Can anyone help me out? What am I doing wrong?

The specific thing I need is the "Gig Paused" text.
I want to contact the seller as soon as the gig is unpaused. :)

Comment: The server is free to send whatever it likes, and can vary responses based on the headers. You'll have to figure out on a trial and error basis what headers your browser sends that make the difference here.

Comment: Moreover, your browser executes any JavaScript sent by the server, which can change what is shown in the browser, including adding additional information loaded from the server using AJAX.

Comment: In other words, this is *not* a problem with `urllib2`, per se.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there no way to figure this out? Except trial and error?

Comment: The server is a black box; unless you have access to the source code of the server, you cannot know what it'll do without trial and error. If the page includes JavaScript, you do have the source code, so start with that. Use the browser developer tools to debug the scripts, and to see what AJAX requests are being made, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That website is sending data gzipped. `urllib2` can't decode it out-of-the-box, but you can access it just fine with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
url = 'http://fiverr.com/logo_business/design-a-killer-high-quality-effective-and-custom-made-logo-for-your-company-business-website-or-personal-use'
print 'Gig Paused' in requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': ''}).text
```

Answer (score 0):

**This problem is browser-dependent (seemingly *Chrome*'and not `urllib2` is at fault)**

This is only a tiny part of an answer, but I hope it helps someone.

I had found the same problem. I tried using `br` and `requests`, to no avail: they all got the same result as `urllib2`, which I assumed to be wrong as it didn't match what I saw on Chrome (Mac OSX 10.10 - Yosemite).

However, further testing with Firefox and Safari successfully retrieved the same url as `urllib2`, and I have confirmed this is the correct one.

So, as Martijn Pieters says, the problem does not seem to have anything to do with urllib2, but ***a lot to do with Chrome***, at least in my case.

My suggestion, if you have a way to tell that this is what is happening in your case, would be to find the link you want on Firefox/Safari, and then implement your code to match that on Python.

Alternatively, you will have to play with the headers until you find what exactly is going on. Again, in my case the Chrome link was simply wrong, so I'd against playing with the headers to match what Chrome shows.